# SSE operations to implement a loop over a 2D array where each output depends on the 3x3 square that contains it (Game of Life)

Tags: c, vectorization, sse, simd

I need to implement SSE (vector operations) to this C module, but cannot reach enough information of this technology, any clue or solution for this?

Also, i'm listening if you have any tips for the code here.

```
void evolution(void *u, int w, int h){

//check_args(c, v);

unsigned (*univ)[w] = u;
unsigned new[h][w];
int itis = args.ITERATIONS;
int actualIteration = 0;

while(itis>0){

    int thisGenerationSeeds = 0;

    for(int y=0;y<h;y++){
        for(int x=0;x<w;x++){
           int n = 0;
           for(int y1=y-1;y1<=y+1;y1++){
               for(int x1=x-1;x1<=x+1;x1++){
                   if(univ[(y1+h)%h][(x1+w)%w]){
                       n++;
                       thisGenerationSeeds++;
                   }
               }
           }
           if(univ[y][x]==1){
               n--;
           }
           new[y][x] = (n==3 || (n==2 && univ[y][x]));
           //thisGenerationSeeds++ = (n==3 || (n==2 && univ[y][x]));

        }
    }   
    itis--;
    actualIteration++;

    printf("\nIteration:_%d, \n Sec Living Seeds:_%d,\n Par Living Seeds:,\n Vec Living Seeds%d",actualIteration, thisGeneration
}
for(int y=0;y<h;y++){
    for(int x=0;x<w;x++){
     univ[y][x] = new[y][x];
    }
}
```

}

Comment: @PeterCordes Thanks for answering! this is the "evolution" function on the "game of life" code.

Comment: @PeterCordes do you have any information source from where i can learn the syntax?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/tags/sse/info has some good links to using Intel's intrinsics.

Comment: It isn't written as an intro-to-SIMD, more like "here's how I used the available intrinsics".  See `computecounts8vec()` in https://github.com/lemire/SIMDgameoflife/blob/master/include/basicautomata.h#L94.

Comment: @PeterCordes with this i can manage to do something, appreciate your efforts :) thanks

Answer (score 1):

Your overall approach should probably be to compute a whole SIMD vector of new elements (or multiple vectors for multiple rows in parallel), rather than trying to do everything for one element before moving on. If you keep enough loaded into local variables (registers), you might be able to work in-place along rows.  Maybe copy 1 row out of 4 to a temporary buffer.

You should probably use `int8_t` elements to get 4 times as many per vector vs. `unsigned`, especially if you can use SSSE3 `_mm_shuffle_epi8` or `_mm_alignr_epi8`, instead of just SSE2 `_mm_shuffle_epi32` or `psrldq` (byte-shift) or unaligned loads to get multiple offsets.

You only ever deal with integers from -1 to 9, so that's all you need for _mm_cmpgt_epi8. You could use 0 / -1 as your true/false states so you can use SIMD compare results directly, without masking to get a 0 / 1. (Add them up by subtracting, i.e. `_mm_sub_epi8`.  Or just add then and negate the constants you compare with).

Each element really only has 1 significant bit, but being able to add up the 9 elements within the same vector width has advantages.  SIMD compares only get as small as bytes.  Still, nibbles can be unpacked efficiently and would double your data density (halve your memory bandwidth).

---

**Dan Lemire published a working implementation of Life using AVX2 intrinsics ([blog post](https://lemire.me/blog/2018/07/18/accelerating-conways-game-of-life-with-simd-instructions/). He got a 25x speedup vs. scalar C** (with optimization enabled of course) on his unspecified machine; I think I remember he said he had a Haswell when I was talking about his UTF-8 validator.

**As he points out, the 3x3 access pattern is the same as many image-processing convolution filters**.  It doesn't look like he implemented circular boundary conditions like yours.  You might make your SIMD loop start/end 1 away from the boundary, and do those elements scalar with wrap-around.

His `computecounts8vec()` at https://github.com/lemire/SIMDgameoflife/blob/master/include/basicautomata.h#L94 uses unaligned-loads to get the offset vectors.  So the `x1+1` 32-byte load overloads the `x1-1` load in the next iteration by 2 bytes.  With 16-byte vectors, using some `_mm_alignr_epi8` to create these shifted windows from two aligned loads can save on unaligned loads, which might be a good idea, but for 32-byte vectors (`__m256i`), the in-lane behaviour makes it nearly useless for its original purpose.

**Computing two or three rows at once would allow more data reuse (the middle row for one output row is the top source-row for the next output row).**  And even reuse of the low+mid sum as the mid+hi sum in the next row down.

Maybe use the `palignr` strategy for one or two rows, and the unaligned-load strategy for the other two in each stripe of 3 or 4 rows you do in one pass.
We're not going to get the usual 2-vectors-per-clock load bandwidth from L1d with unaligned loads, because of slowdowns from crossing cache-line boundaries.  It's still only 1 uop, but it takes two accesses to L1d.  So replacing some load uops with shuffle uops is good up to a point, especially on AMD CPUs where shuffle throughput is higher and 32-byte vectors are only worth it if it doesn't take extra shuffling.  (They're split into two 16-byte operations on AMD, unlike Intel.)

I wonder if we can use a less-dense encoding that has padding or repeats an element every chunk to allow loading just a single vector and shifting it to get the offsets.

Or maybe a more-dense encoding that we have to expand anyway (like packed bits), so we have the extra data loaded.

---

### Code review

Using new as a variable name in C is aggressively hostile to programmers who also know C++. I'd recommend another name so this code is also valid C++, for compilers that implement C99 VLAs in C++. Also, have the caller pass in the src and destination buffers, and use `unsigned *__restrict dst[h]`, `unsigned *__restrict src[h]` so the compiler knows they don't overlap. Then you can alternate between two buffers instead of doing a copy-and-whatever + copy-back every time.

Handle the wrapping boundary-coundition specially, instead of putting `(x1+w)%w` into the inner-most loop. That will most likely compile to a hardware `idiv` instruction because compilers probably don't figure out that it can only wrap once, and `w` is not a compile-time constant. (Unless it is after inlining.) This is probably the major bottleneck in your scalar code.

Comment: I do believe a bit-per-cell packing, where you store the world in (any power of two-sized) word-width stripes, with the least significant nibble copied from the most significant nibble in the next stripe, yields excellent density and computational efficiency: all you need is binary AND, OR, and NOT operations, addition (no nibble will ever overflow), and bit shifts. No lookups or conditionals needed. The 'trick' is to calculate each result word in four separate parts, deinterleaving the bits.